# IText Error "The type com.itextpdf.XXX is not accessible"

Tags: java, maven, itext, maven-plugin, itext7

I have this problem for 2 days I did all possible research.

```
import com.itextpdf.io.font.constants.StandardFonts;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFont;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFontFactory;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.canvas.parser.PdfTextExtractor;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.layout.properties.TextAlignment;
```

All import are with errors "The type com.itextpdf.XXX is not accessible".

I followed the installation tutorial with maven, here is my pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>pdf_dem</groupId>
  <artifactId>pdf_dem</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <release>18</release>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  
  <properties>
   <itext.version>7.2.4</itext.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- add all iText 7 modules -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext7-core</artifactId>
        <version>${itext.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

</project>
```

Thank you for you precious help :)

I modify pom.xml as stated in the Itext guideline [https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/installation-guidelines/installing-itext-7-for-java]

Comment: Can you explain why you have configured that: `<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>`??? I strongly recommend to stick with conventions meaning directories: Java source in `src/main/java/<package>` unit tests in `src/test/java/<package>/XYTest.java` and resources for code in `src/main/resources/...` and for tests only `src/test/resources`...

Comment: How does the module-info.java look like?

Answer (score 0):

The pom.xml and presumably the java file are looking fine.
I just created a project to reproduce your problem, but it was not possible when `mvn package` (java file is in `src/itext/Main.java`).

```
package itext;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFontFactory;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PdfFontFactory pdfFontFactory = new PdfFontFactory();
        System.out.printf("Factory: %s%n", pdfFontFactory);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Factory: com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFontFactory@3d075dc0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Perhaps you should keep an eye on what is your jdk-version, maven-version.

Also check if there is special settings in maven (settings.xml), check output of `mvn package -X` if everything is fine.

Try if you at least can make it work in your IDE that comes w/ Maven support.